# Обработка readyState

Tags: javascript

Здравствуйте.

Есть пример кода:

```
var body = document.body || document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0];
var rand = Math.floor(Math.random( ) * (9999999+1));
var new_img = document.createElement('IMG');
new_img.src = "https://i.stack.imgur.com/P8RF4.png?r="+rand;
body.appendChild(new_img);

if(new_img.readyState) { // для IE
    new_img.onreadystatechange = function () {
        if(new_img.readyState == 'complete' || new_img.readyState == 'loaded') {
            new_img.onreadystatechange = null;
            alert('УСПЕШНО ЗАГРУЖЕНО'); // выполняется даже если изображение не загружено
        }
    }
}
```

Как прикрутить отлов ошибок? В других браузерах это выглядит например так:

```
new_img.onerror = function(){alert('ОШИБКА ЗАГРУЗКИ');}
```

Comment: Код нужно выкинуть, он стар как дарьмо мамонта, а отлов ошибок загрузки изображения вообще не существует, тоже была подобная заморочка.
И да - не нужно путать AJAX и загрузку изображений.

Comment: alert-ы уж точно никто уже не использует. Используйте конструкцию `try ... catch`. [Почитайте](https://learn.javascript.ru/exception). И, главное, про асинхронность не забывайте.

Comment: > В других браузерах это выглядит например так: > new_img.onerror = function(){alert('ОШИБКА ЗАГРУЗКИ');} Вообще-то везде так...

Answer (score 1):

Проверить свойство XMLHttpRequest.status на значение 200.

Пример из вики:

```
function processReqChange()
{
  try { // Важно!
    // только при состоянии "complete"
    if (req.readyState == 4) {
        // для статуса "OK"
        if (req.status == 200) {
            // обработка ответа
        } else {
            alert("Не удалось получить данные:\n" +
                req.statusText);
        }
    }
  }
  catch( e ) {
      // alert('Ошибка: ' + e.description);
      // В связи с багом XMLHttpRequest в Firefox приходится отлавливать ошибку
      // Bugzilla Bug 238559 XMLHttpRequest needs a way to report networking errors
      // https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=238559
  }
}
```

Comment: Мне нужно подключить картинку, к странице. С этим собственно проблем нет. Проблема возникает с браузером Internet Explorer (ver 7, 8), в случае, если картинка недоступна. Нужно вывести простой АЛЕРТ, информирующий об ошибке.